# How to pass a class with an abstract class type as parameter in parcelable android studio java

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am trying to pass this class as a parcelable in android.

```
public class Outfit implements Parcelable {

    private List<Item> itemList;
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Outfit() {}

    public Outfit(String mName, String mImageUrl) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;

    }

    protected Outfit(Parcel in) {
        itemList = in.createTypedArrayList(Item.CREATOR);
        mName = in.readString();
        mImageUrl = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Outfit> CREATOR = new Creator<Outfit>() {
        @Override
        public Outfit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Outfit(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Outfit[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Outfit[size];
        }
    };

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeTypedList(itemList);
        parcel.writeString(mName);
        parcel.writeString(mImageUrl);
    }
}
```

the problem is that Item is abstract and itemList = in.creatTypedArrayList(Item.CREATOR) because Item does not have a CREATOR . Only its subclasses have this implementation.

Item.java

```
public abstract class Item implements Parcelable {

    private String mName;

    private String mColor;

    private String mImageUrl;

    private List<TagHolder> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    private String mKey;

    public Item(){

    }

    public Item(String mName, String mColor, String mImageUrl) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mColor = mColor;
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }

    protected Item(Parcel in) {
        mName = in.readString();
        mColor = in.readString();
        mImageUrl = in.readString();
        tags = in.createTypedArrayList(TagHolder.CREATOR);
        mKey = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(mName);
        dest.writeString(mColor);
        dest.writeString(mImageUrl);
        dest.writeTypedList(tags);
        dest.writeString(mKey);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    public void setmName(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public void setmImageUrl(String mImageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }

    public List<TagHolder> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public String getmColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public String getmImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setmColor(String mColor) {
        this.mColor = mColor;
    }

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setTags(List<TagHolder> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    @Exclude // dont need this in our firebase database
    public String getKey() {
        return mKey;
    }

    @Exclude
    public void setMkey(String key) {
        mKey = key;
    }

    public abstract String getCategory();
}
```

I am able to parce a List as a parcelable array when I call put extra. But when I try to do so for outfit it gives error . Is there any way to pass Outfit as a parcelable?

Comment: Why is it abstract? Can u create object of abstract?

Comment: Yes I can instantiate Shirts,Pants which extend from Item, so what happens is that the the user can choose his Shirt,Pants,etc and It will be added to this itemList. And this itemList forms an outfit. But I want to be able to pass this outfit with itemList as a parameter to another activity if possible. If its not possible I would try to think of another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try using another method for the list?

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeList(itemList);
    parcel.writeString(mName);
    parcel.writeString(mImageUrl);
}

protected Outfit(Parcel in) {
    in.readList(itemList, Item.class.getClassLoader());
    mName = in.readString();
    mImageUrl = in.readString();
}
```

Comment: Hmm I would try This code there isn't any compile errors . Thank you !

Comment: it says Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference and the error is at the line in.readList(itemList,Item.class.getClassLoader() when I tried to test it with a dummy object though >.<

Comment: Initialize your List like you do in your abstract class

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: You have to do this private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>(); on your Outfit class.